# Default value in select triggering Javascript method

Tags: javascript, html

how to let a select trigger a javascript method when the select is being populated and set to default value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You use on change event  to trigger method on change of select.

Comment: i have updated my  answer please accept so that it can help others as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily been done with the [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler.

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val() == 'default') { 
    console.log('selected default'); 
  } else {
    $('p').text($(this).val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="default"></option>
  <option value="Hello World!">Hello</option>
  <option value="Foo and Bar are common used example names">Foo</option>
</select>
<p>Please pick an option.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. I used onchange="myFunction" before. But your way is to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use on change event to handle it .

Javacript/Jquery

```
function printData() {
        console.log("On change of the select box your this fuction will get call");
    }

$(document).ready (function () {

    $('select').change(function(){
                  printData();
    });
})
```

HTML

```
<lable>Select option.</lable>
    <select>
      <option value="1">Hi</option>
      <option value="2">Hello</option>
      <option value="3">How are you</option>
    </select>
```